# CDI Injection Outside Filters and Servlets in a Servlet 3.0 Container

Tags: tomcat, cdi, jboss-weld

I finally decided to have a look at Weld in Tomcat. When I deploy my app I see in the log:

"Tomcat 7 detected, CDI injection will be available in Servlets and Filters"

How can for example create an instance of a bean using the BeanManager outside a Filter/Servlet?

I have a bean:

```
@javax.inject.Named(value="CarService")
@javax.enterprise.context.RequestScoped
public class CarService implements Serializable{
.
.
.
```

and I want to create an instance of it using the BeanManager for the specified request context.

```
Context ctx = new InitialContext();
BeanManager manager = (BeanManager) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/BeanManager");
// NOW WHAT?
```

If this can be done in a servlet/filter I am sure it can be done anywhere else but I just do not want to go through the Weld code and figure it out myself without asking first.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I didn't get it. What are you trying to do? In which class do you want to use this bean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the `BeanManager` is something that you should rarely do. The point is to use `@Inject` in places where you need dependencies (which is dependency injection). Using the manager is the "service-locator" pattern.

If you really need it, use `manager.getBeans(yourDesiredClass)`, then pick one from the set and call `manager.getReference(bean, theClass, ctx)`. `ctx` will be obtained by `manager.createCreationalContext(bean)`

Comment: Thanks for the help! The reason I needed is because I want BlazeDS to use the BeanManager which will allow me to use injections in service objects. So I think this is a case where it is actually needed. The method manager.resolve(manager.getBeans(type)) resolves the bean for me without the need to go through the set as you advised.

Comment: aha. the flex integration indeed looks like a place where interaction with the bean manager might be needed.

Answer (score 2):

I already used this Seam code which gave me all I needed.

```
public static <T> T getContextualInstance(final BeanManager manager, final Class<T> type) {
        T result = null;
        Bean<T> bean = (Bean<T>) manager.resolve(manager.getBeans(type));
        if (bean != null) {
            CreationalContext<T> context = manager.createCreationalContext(bean);
            if (context != null) {
                result = (T) manager.getReference(bean, type, context);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
```